# Alignment Issue with Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, alignment

Help, I'm a beginner on code! Can someone tell me the code to get the form to go beside the picture instead of under it? Right now the picture is cropped even though I said to show the full thing.

http://mycolorshop.com/wedding-questionnaire

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your theme's css file to float the form next to the image.

```
.page-id-297 .ccf-form-wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
}
```

When I look at your source, I'm seeing the entire image that Wordpress is serving displayed. Did you unintentionally crop the image in the editor?

Comment: This worked, thanks a bunch cpiko! It shows the entire image too!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to your website.

```
.form-id-425 {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   width: 500px;
}
```

This floats your form container to the left, the same float position as the image. The width makes it small enough to fit the space.